# Am trying to send a message on Codeigniter 4 but i keep having this error

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function send_mail()
{
    $email = \Config\Services::email();

    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['SMTPHost'] = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
    $config['SMTPUser'] = '[obscured]';
    $config['SMTPPass'] = '[obscured]';
    $config['SMTPPort'] = 25;
    $config['SMTPCrypto'] = 'tls';
    $config['mailType'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";


    $email->initialize($config);

    $email->setFrom('bra0@gmail.com', 'Brainyworld');
    $email->setTo('usm@gmail.com');

    $email->setSubject('Email Test');
    $email->setMessage('Testing the email class.');

    $email->send(false);
    echo $email->printDebugger(['header']);


        }
```

and here is the error am having

hello: 
The following SMTP error was encountered:
starttls: 
The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: if these are real email credentials you are seriously compromising the security of this email account by posting username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solved this problem by changing my SMTPPort from 25 to 2525 and my message start sending.